# To Hyperspace and higher dimensions

Tags: propulsion, research

Has any actual work been done on the idea of traveling to higher dimensions, as a shortcut through space? Plenty of sci-fi books use this concept, but I want to know if there is any research being conducted on this concept. (I'm not talking about all of the warp drive research.)

Comment: I assume by "warp drive" you mean Alcubierre's idea of a warped bubble of space, and variants of that?

Comment: Yes, it is commonly mistaken with a hyperdrive

Comment: It turns out that by moving through a 4th timelike dimension it is possible to travel arbitrary distances in 3-dimensional space! (Controlling the magnitude and sign of the 4th velocity term turns out to be problematic though.)

Comment: NASA spends money (fortunately, a small amount of money) on "beyond the mainstream" notions (aka crackpot). This falls in that category.

Comment: I've been thinking a lot about this subject lately. M-Theory postulates a number of additional dimensions in spacetime, including an extra time dimension. The additional spatial dimensions are usually considered to be so tightly curled up that they are not directly observable.

Comment: @DavidHammen There *are* legitimate theories postulating large extra dimensions (LEDs), but as I have pointed out in my answer there is currently no experimental or observational evidence for these theories. So, if NASA were funding the idea of some "innovator" who claimed to have a method to access LEDs, this is extremely unlikely to be fruitful since we don't even have a validated model for the existence of LEDs. On the other hand, if NASA were funding the research at the LHC which could support or falsify legitimate theories about the existence of LEDs, this would not be worthless.

Comment: If the LHC *did* find evidence supporting the existence of LEDs, it could potentially open up an avenue to the development of some form of hyperspace travel, which if possible would be quite transformative.

Comment: So far, no theory or experiment addresses the fundamental nature of space time. I see science as a vast effort to reverse engineer the universe. We're just figuring out how it all works. Newton discovered the laws of gravity, but he didn't invent gravity, nor did Einstein invent relativity. He just figured out how it works. We probably have a really long way to go before we can begin to change the nature of reality, and maybe it's good that I won't be around to see that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Imagine two parallel lines. You are a line segment on the lower line, and your perception is completely limited to your line. All objects you are aware of are oriented along the line. You theorize there might be a higher spatial dimension and that there might be another line above you in this second dimension. You would like to construct a bridge to the other line, but you have a problem. In order to bridge the two lines, you have to already have a two dimensional object: an angle. Without an angle, you cannot create a bridge between the two lines. No one has ever observed an angle, and no method to create an angle is known.

This is the problem we are facing with the proposition of hyperspace. No one has ever observed another spatial dimension. We don't know how to access hyperspace, if it exists.

See: [Brane cosmology - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brane_cosmology#Empirical_tests)

Comment: "No one has ever observed another spatial dimension..." I did once, but that was with some "assistance" during my heady undergraduate "travels".